# How to use Vertex Array objects?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to learn to use OpenGL 4.5 using the book "OpenGL Superbible 7th edition". The way it explains VAOs is this:

```
   GLuint compile_shaders(){
    GLuint vertex_shader;
    GLuint fragment_shader;
    GLuint program;


    //shader code



    //create and compile vertex shader
    vertex_shader=glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);             //create shader object
    glShaderSource(vertex_shader,1,vertex_shader_source,NULL);  //puts shader code in object
    glCompileShader(vertex_shader);             //compiles shader source code

    //create and compile fragment shader
    fragment_shader=glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_shader,1,fragment_shader_source,NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment_shader);

    //create program, attach shaders, and link it
    program=glCreateProgram();                //creates program to attach shader objects
    glAttachShader(program,vertex_shader);      //attaches shader to program
    glAttachShader(program,fragment_shader);
    glLinkProgram(program);                     //links all shader objects in program

    //delete shaders because program already has them now
    glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);          //deletes shader (code is already in program)
    glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);



return program;
}


//startup
GLuint program=compile_shaders();
    GLuint vertex_array_object;
    glCreateVertexArrays(1,&vertex_array_object);
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object);


//drawing 
glUseProgram(program);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);
```

Whenever I try to compile this it gives me a compiler error saying that glCreateArrays was not declared. If glCreateVertexArrays is not an opengl function then how do you use VAOs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whenever I try to compile this it gives me a compiler error saying that glCreateArrays was not declared.

`glCreateVertexArrays` is an OpenGL function, and has been for well over a year now. If your program won't compile with it, then odds are good that your [OpenGL loading library](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) is out of date. Download a more recent one or switch to one that isn't broken.

Comment: Isn't the function called `glCreateVertexArrays`?

Comment: @BDL: The actual code he posted used the right function name. ;)

Answer (score -2):

Like this -

```
GLuint VAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO); // Generate a vertex array.
glBindVertexArray(VAO); // bind it
```

I don't know the exact details but everything you do after binding it will be 
stored inside of the VAO.

You can create one buffer for the vertex positions, and one for the colors.

something like this -

```
GLuint posVerBuffer;

//Position
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posVerBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, position.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &position[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0); // Position

// Similar for the color
```

After you're done you unbind it.

```
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Now everytime you want to draw this specific VAO, you just bind it.

```
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
```

This tutorial has pages on everything, and teaches *modern* OpenGL - http://learnopengl.com/

Comment: He's trying to use the ARB_direct_state_access functions, which are core OpenGL and have been since 4.5.